# variable length line in a file deletion in C

Tags: c, file, fgets, fputs

I have a file main.txt and I want to delete a line in this file that contains a number passed as an argument to the program.

My code:

```
FILE *temp = fopen("main.txt","r");
FILE *copy = fopen("temp.txt","w+");
char line[25]; //lines won't be more than this length
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), temp)!=NULL)
{ 
     char *s;
     s = strstr(line, argv[2]));
     if(s!=NULL)
          continue;
     else
          fputs(line,copy);
}

fclose(temp);
fclose(copy);
remove("main.txt");
rename("temp.txt", "main.txt");
```

Case where this fails:

Currently my file has:

```
echo hello 24224
echo test123 24196
echo bye 13279
```

When I try to remove the line with 24196, it doesn't copy the last line to the new file. Using ltrace shows that after strstr returns a non NULL value, fgets gets an emty string. How can I fix this, what is going wrong here?

```
__libc_start_main(0x402636, 3, 0x7ffcee2a2078, 0x4036b0 <unfinished ...>
strcmp("unmanage", "unmanage")                   = 0
fopen("pid1.txt", "r")                           = 0x19ee010
fopen("temp.txt", "w+")                          = 0x19ee240
fgets("echo hello 30876\n", 25, 0x19ee010)       = 0x7ffcee2a1f60
strstr("echo hello 30876\n", "5785")             = nil
fputs("echo hello 30876\n", 0x19ee240)           = 1
fgets("echo lame 9047\n", 25, 0x19ee010)         = 0x7ffcee2a1f60
strstr("echo lame 9047\n", "5785")               = nil
fputs("echo lame 9047\n", 0x19ee240)             = 1
fgets("echo trial 5785\n", 25, 0x19ee010)        = 0x7ffcee2a1f60
strstr("echo trial 5785\n", "5785")              = "5785\n"
fgets("", 25, 0x19ee010)                         = 0x7ffcee2a1f60
strstr("", "5785")                               = nil
fputs("", 0x19ee240)                             = 1
fgets("", 25, 0x19ee010)                         = 0x7ffcee2a1f60
strstr("", "5785")                               = nil
fputs("", 0x19ee240)                             = 1
fgets("", 25, 0x19ee010)                         = 0x7ffcee2a1f60
strstr("", "5785")                               = nil
fputs("", 0x19ee240)                             = 1
fgets("", 25, 0x19ee010)                         = 0x7ffcee2a1f60
strstr("", "5785")                               = nil
fputs("", 0x19ee240)                             = 1
fgets("", 25, 0x19ee010)                         = 0
fclose(0x19ee010)                                = 0
fclose(0x19ee240)                                = 0
remove("pid1.txt")                               = 0
rename("temp.txt", "pid1.txt")                   = 0
atoi(0x7ffcee2a320f, 0x403aca, 0, 0x7fde8ca22367) = 5785
kill(5785, SIGTERM)                              = 0
 +++ exited (status 0) +++
```

Comment: What is the value of argv[1]? and argv[2] ?

Comment: argv[1]: will be a string called "remove" and if it matches, I will get into this block to delete the line containing the string in argv[2], the numbers in the file.

Comment: @someone1 I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have added my ltrace output.

Comment: "Currently my file has" does not match "ltrace".  Positing consistent source file and trace would help.

Comment: Using `temp` with `"main.txt"` and `copy` with `"temp.txt"` adds confution.  Suggest  aligning text names with variables.